# Pull data from disabled device

Tags: adb, internal-storage, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6, with a completely disabled screen. I want to pull recent images and data from it. USB Debugging is enabled, but the phone needs a passcode for me to access its' data. Is there any way I can enter the passcode or access the data remotely?