# Data Acquisition/Live Boot/Flashing What Can I Run using USB on a Boot Looping Android Device?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, boot-loop, boot, usb-debugging

I am wondering if there might be a way for me to get some to "live boot" my [bootlooping](https://xdaforums.com/t/closed-bootloop-crashing.4658913/) Samsung Galaxy S7 G930A (AT&T model, qualcomm snapdragon with locked bootloader) for [data recovery purposes](https://xdaforums.com/t/encrypted-dump-from-malfunctioning-phone.4659450/).

I saw an [answer discussing booting SoC's from a usb drive](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220677/how-to-boot-ubuntu-persistent-live-usb-on-android) and another [answer specifically regarding this sort of thing for samsung devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40419/is-it-possible-to-boot-an-android-phone-from-a-usb-drive)

I dont need a custom rom, I can use a signed one, anything I can get to boot or interact with the device (usb-debugging from PC? fastboot?) without deleting my files currently on the device.

I also have some confusion about flashing, as normally it seems like this [destroys the data on the device](https://xdaforums.com/t/closed-bootloop-crashing.4658913/post-89370887) There is a [comment here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221357/android-device-cant-boot#comment348106_221357) seeming to say otherwise and an [article](https://www.forensicfocus.com/articles/physical-imaging-of-a-samsung-galaxy-s7-smartphone-running-android-7-0/) suggesting that you can "flash" an ENG_ROOT image and non-destructively recover data (found that article from another interesting article [here](https://blog.elcomsoft.com/2017/10/ios-vs-android-physical-data-extraction-and-data-protection-compared/)).

Is it possible to interact with the device and retrieve data (even encrypted data) via some sort of "live boot" or interaction via USB without using booting a (possibly corrupt) image already on the device or while its "off"? Also some clarity about flashing and if it *has* to be destructive to the data on the device would be nice.

### Notes

- I am "Developer" on the device, but I think USB debugging was disabled and I dont know about ADB (used it once, but think it was disabled).
- I saw [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205297/galaxy-s7-edge-change-usb-mode-in-phone-that-will-not-boot) about a S7 Edge, but I am not necessarily trying to get it in usable shape again, just recover data for now.
- There is [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110312/boot-from-an-image-in-pc-using-android-device) as well, but its older and I don't know if the same knowledge applies today or to this specific device with a locked bootloader (other posts seem to indicate it may not).
- There is [acquisition](https://github.com/mesquidar/ForensicsTools?tab=readme-ov-file#acquisition) software like [andriller](https://github.com/den4uk/andriller) but I just dont know if I can use it from the devices state.
- Willing to try and get root
- No one seems to have answered [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172796/pull-data-from-disabled-device) question, my question is not exactly the same (I ask about what I can do via usb for recovery purposes) but its related

Thank you! - TFB

Comment: If the bootloader is locked then you can boot only kernel images signed by Samsung. And I have not yet seen an Android phone that is capable of booting from USB or SD-card.

Comment: There are some signed images available I also some ENG_ROOT images.